# Is it possible to use python aerospike client to read blob data inserted with JAVA client

Tags: aerospike

Whenever I use `query.results()` on my query for aformentioned blob data I get empty array, `query.foreach(dummy)` with dummy callback produces segmentation fault, data blob was inserted using JAVA client with no custom serialization

Answer (score 3):

When you are writing blob data using Java, if you are using byte array as bin type, you should be able to read it in python. If you are creating bin with `Object` datatype, the java serializer will be used to write the blob. You cannot reach such blob in python.

Comment: thanks, I think it was Double serialized which indicates second (non-python compatibility) scenario, I guess I need to use JAVA client

Comment: See the documentation about subtle points in handling of double datatypes in Java client. http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/Bin.html#Bin(java.lang.String,%20double).

Answer (score 1):

Aerospike has a list of [supported data types](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/data-types.html), which currently is integer, double, string, bytes (blob), list, map, geoJSON. Native language types will map directly to and from the supported types, so in Python the client converts [str](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#str) to [as_string](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-common/blob/master/src/include/aerospike/as_string.h), [int](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#int) to [as_integer](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-common/blob/master/src/include/aerospike/as_integer.h), [float](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#float) to [as_double](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-common/blob/master/src/include/aerospike/as_double.h), etc.

The way the Python client would [serialize](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/aerospike.html#aerospike.calc_digest) in and out of a BLOB is into a [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#bytearray). The Java client should use the [Bin.asBlob()](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/Bin.html#asBlob(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) method ahead of writing the record.